# Disable moving of html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

please check out this page.
[Check Out](http://99-tech-tools.blogspot.com/2017/01/facebook-like-button-generator.html)
As you can see i tried to add a live preview. I used jQuery html() to add elements to webpage. But 
when anyone  click on generate button the elements moves a little upward to add a new elements 'live preview'.Is there any way to remove this moving? 
Sorry for bad English(;

```
    <input id="url" type="text" value="http://"/><br/>
    <button id="btn">Generate</button><br/>  
<div id="opt">
&nbps;
</div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"         type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btn").click(function ()
 {
$("#opt").html ("Live Preview");
});
</script>
```

something like this.
Also why the Live Preview text having large padding from above element.

Comment: `please check out this page` - absolutely not. Put code that demonstrates the issue in the question

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. This is necessary not only to make verification and debugging of the problem as straightforward as possible for us, but also to preserve the validity of the question, once the problem is fixed on the live website. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Remove the `&nbsp;` from `<div class="error">`

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have used `&nbsp;` for padding in `<div class="error">`

It is removed by the jquery command `$(".error").text("");` when the button is pressed. Either remove the `&nbsp;` in the original code (space will never exist), or change the jquery command to add it after the button is pressed (space will always exist).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the none breaking space `&nbsp;` from `<div class="error">&nbsp;</div>`

Or you can just move the errors div below. Like this:

```
<div class="center">
    <br>
    <input id="url" type="text" value="http://"><br>
    <button id="btn">Generate</button><br>
    <input type="text" id="opt" placeholder="Generated Code will be here!">
<div class="error">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```